# Spring information about start and video references

Tags: spring

I am very very new to Spring and I don't even know Java EE. Can I proceed with Spring? If not , then how and what things do I have to gain before moving to Spring?

Please also guide me spring flavour and the best books for the specified flavours.

Please also give brief about each flavor so that I can gain knowledge about what is used for what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to learn Java EE for learning Spring. Spring is not Java EE and Java EE is not spring. You can develop Java EE application using spring and without spring.

From the wikipedia : The Spring Framework is an open source application framework and inversion of control container for the Java platform.

Before moving to spring, you should be acquinted with design patterns. Effective Java and Head First Design Pattern is a good book to start. You can also find multiple source online.

Once you through about design pattern. You can find the Spring very much easy and its uses.

Start with Spring core. Then move to the other sub-projects of spring.

Documentation in Spring Source is best place to start..

Answer (score 0):

You have to first learn `Java EE` especially `JSP` and `Servlets`. Get some detailed information on `MVC` pattern. You also require some hands-on knowledge on `Web servers`. Then you can move on to learn `Spring`.

Comment: Hmmm any sites which i can refer to

Comment: @KnowledgeSeaker Instead of websites, refer books such as **Head first Servlets and JSP**. Practice, making a small project. And then for _Spring_ refer to book **Spring in action** and **Apress Spring recipies**.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very subjective question; what teaching aides work best depend on the individual. As far as videos go, I would start with youtube with the springsource channel for Spring related information, and even some Java EE 101 type stuff. Also have a look at slideshare.net for presentations on various Java EE and Spring topics. good luck!

Comment: i am watching vedios but hope that wont be suficient so need a good book to understand the concepts can you refer any.